# Check size of HTTP POST without saving to disk

Tags: python, pyramid

Is there a way to check the size of the incoming POST in Pyramid, without saving the file to disk and using the `os` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to check the `request.content_length`. WSGI does not support streaming the request body so content length must be specified. If you ever access `request.body`, `request.params` or `request.POST` it will read the content and save it to disk.

The best way to handle this, however, is as close to the client as possible. Meaning if you are running behind a proxy of any sort, have that proxy reject requests that are too large. Once it gets to Python, something else may have already stored the request to disk.

Comment: Oh thats interesting to know. Thanks!